# What is a "profanity" in SE Workplace?

Tags: discussion

#### Context

My [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/193031/25229):

> I would add the case where your coworker is insecure, megalomaniac or an asshole, doing a pissing contest (not sure if there is a professional wording for that)

The edit:

> I would add the case where your coworker is insecure, megalomaniac or establishing the pecking order,

Rationale for the edit: *Removed unnecessary profanity*

*Profanity* [according to](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/profanity) the Oxford Advanced American Dictionary:

> [uncountable] behavior that shows a lack of respect for God or holy things
> [countable, usually plural] swear words, or religious words used in a way that shows a lack of respect for God or holy things

#### Question

Aside from the fact that I would be curious how someone can be offended by my words *from a religious perspective* (I am genuinely curious, please note that I am French and an atheist) - I feel that smoothing out all the language and removing any such dirty words (well, at least dirty for some) is condescending.

The words in question are "asshole" and "pissing contest".

And then there was a very good comment (authoritatively deleted) which was playing on my words - but this you would not see as it is gone for good without any trial.

But this is my opinion - and I am curious about others.

Note: I will not go into an edit war which would turn out into a <del>pissing contest</del>, sorry, pecking order I meant.

Comment: " I feel that smoothing out all the language and removing any such dirty words (well, at least dirty for some) is condescending." - so do you feel that everyone's words should remain intact, so as not to be condescending?

Comment: People often do not distinguish between profanity and vulgarity.  I would contend the words are vulgar but not profane, as you rightly point out they have nothing to do with religion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited your answer after it was brought to my attention with a flag. I didn't want to take any other action as the answer itself was ok. But if it's being flagged, then for some they're reading the words rather than the meaning which detracts from the answers usefulness. (I wasn't personally offended, I find online English profanity more amusing than offensive.)

I'd prefer to see a useful answer being considered seriously, than dismissed as offensive, so I tried to keep the meaning as close to your intention as possible.

But you're always free to roll back edits if you feel the need.

Comment: I specifically did not want to point you out (as the editor) because I did not know whether this was a personal reaction or a heap of flags. If this one is a single one I would say that this is an overreaction - but then I do not have to deal with zillions of flags every day as I am not a moderator. I do appreciate your answer above as well. I am more saddened by the removal of the comment as it was specifically playing on the words of the answer.

Comment: This said, I am offended (for personal reasons so do not ask because it is offensive to ask) by the word "octothorpe" and "stupendously" so I will flag them in the future (just kidding, just kidding). +1 for the reasonable answer BTW

Comment: I'm fine with owning up to my deeds/misdeeds. Once I edited the answer the comment became obsolete so I removed it. No malice or religious zealotry involved. I'm not an athiest but wasn't offended.